# WCF service need to call Asynchronous

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous

i am trying to call WCF service asynchronously using client .
for that in reference i selected  generate asynchronous operation, 
problem is if i call same service 10 time , control goes to completed delegate once all 100 service finish and in response its give same time for all 100 service .
for ex - like this i not able to get response time of each call as all call response return on same time .
this is my code for call the service

```
wsClient.GetCustomerGeoCodeCompleted += (sender, args) => client_GetCustomerGeoCodeCompleted(sender, args);
wsClient.GetCustomerGeoCodeAsync(GetCustomerGeoCodeRequest, lintRequestCount.ToString());
```

this one is my delegate

```
public void client_GetCustomerGeoCodeCompleted(object sender, wsIntegrationService.GetCustomerGeoCodeCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
           // lintResponseCount += 1;
            WriteLog(strResponseLogpath, e.UserState + " - SUCCESS -  Get Customer Geo - " + "Record Received" + e.Result.Count().ToString()) + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss:FFF"));

        }
        else
        {
            WriteLog(logpath, "ERROR -> : Get Customer Geo " + e.Error.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        WriteLog(logpath, "ERROR -> : Get Customer Geo " + ex.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

any suggestion how i can get repose as soon as service call finish for that request .

Comment: Are you using 100 different instances  at the client side or rather, you are reusing the very same instance?

Comment: hi @WiktorZychla  i creating instance inside loop  . so instance will create every time

Answer (score 0):

i added awaits in call and work as needed

```
await Task.Run(() => wsClient.GetSalesOrderV1Async(GetSalesOrderRequest, lintRequestCount.ToString() +"-"+  dr["TenantCode"].ToString()));
```

let me know if any other approach